# CDH4.4: Restarting HDFS and MapReduce from shell

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

I'm trying to automate stopping, formatting and starting HDFS and MapReduce services on a Cloudera Hadoop 4.4 cluster, using a bash script.

It's easy to kill HDFS and MapReduce processes using "pkill -U hdfs && pkill -U mapred", but how can I start those processes again, without using the Cloudera Manager GUI?

Comment: Why can't you make use of CM for restart? , reinventing wheel !!

Comment: I want to automate it using a script. I only know how to use CM using the GUI

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently CM has a pretty sweet API

Check it out here

http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/